# How do I sum the total of books sold based on title of the book?

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image: Screenshot]

```
select b.ISBN, b.title, a.author_name, b.unit_price, p.quantity
from books as b left join
     purchases as p
     on b.ISBN = p.book_id left join
     authors as a
     on b.author_id = a.id;
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by :

```
select
    b.ISBN,
    b.title,
    a.author_name,
    b.unit_price,
    sum(p.quantity) as Sold
from
    books as b
    left join purchases as p on b.ISBN = p.book_id
    left join authors as a on b.author_id = a.id
group by
    b.ISBN,
    b.title,
    a.author_name,
    b.unit_price
```